# task scheduler on windows throws error "2147942402"

Tags: php, windows, taskscheduler

I am trying to schedule a task in windows task scheduler what i want is have to run a url every 5 minutes without opening browser i tried using

> php -f http://localhost/sms/test.php
>
> wget -q -O - http://localhost/sms/test.php > tmp.txt

and also the full path

> php -f C:/Bitnami/redmine-2.4.3-0/apache2/htdocs/sms/test.php

it shows the same error

> Task Scheduler failed to start instance
>   "{a889332e-87f0-421b-accc-4ff19ae98599}" of "\test"  task for user
>   "PUGOSTECH\xxxxx" . Additional Data: Error Value: 2147942402.

I understand that i am making a silly mistake to create scheduler but dont know how to find?
If i use by opening browser command it works fine like

> cmd /c start http://localhost/sms/test.php